# Timers and actionPerformed in java

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

So all i'm trying to do is make a ball bounce around a window, but for some reason, while no red flags are raised on eclipse, when i run it, it just displays a static ball.

This is what i got so far:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Pong extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    int x=600, y=250, vx=5, vy=5;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Pong p = new Pong();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(1400, 700);
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(100, p);
        t.start();  
        t.addActionListener(p);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics b){
        b.fillOval(x,y, 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(y>700||y<0) {
            vy=-vy;
        }
        if(x>1400||x<0) {
            vx=-vx;
        }
        y=y+vy;
        x=x+vx;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `actionPerformed()` method you need to tell Swing to repaint your Panel (by calling its `repaint()` method for example), otherwise it has no way of knowing that you changed something.

Comment: You may want to add the imports to your code sample to help people who are trying to build your code.  The `Timer` class for example, is ambiguous.  (Could be `java.util.Timer` or `javax.swing.Timer`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a call to `repaint()` at the end of `actionPerformed`.  Note that this will lead to other painting problems (the ball just gets smeared across the screen) because you also need to call `super.paintComponent(b);` as the first thing in your `paintComponent` method.

Also there is no need to call `t.addActionListener(p)`, as the `ActionListener` has already been added by the call to `new Timer(100, p)`.  Since the `ActionListener` is now actually added twice, `actionPerformed` gets called twice per timer pop and your ball moves two times faster than you intended.

Note also that as you currently have it, the process will never end until it is killed.  You need to make sure you dispose of your JFrame:

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

and shutdown your `Timer`:

```
final Timer t = new Timer(100, p);  // need to make this final to avoid compile error
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        t.stop();
    }
});
```

I noticed that I had a bunch of "Pong" processes still running after testing your code. :)

Comment: The `ActionListener` is added explicitly when creating the `Timer`, `t.addActionListener(p);` is actually a bad idea, as the OP has now registered the same listener twice, meaning they will be notified twice...but +1 for including `super.paintComponent`

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are totally right.  I wasn't even looking at that!  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The timer must ask the panel to repaint itself:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    ...
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [repaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) on the `JPanel` or it will not have any reason to repaint itself.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    ...

    this.repaint(this.getVisibleRect());
}
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

You should call repaint after you modify a location. for example

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(y>700||y<0) {
             vy=-vy;
             repaint();
          }...
```